# Buildozer converting apk fail

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy

When i try kivy to apk in github actions or google colab or ubuntu virtual machine it give this error

```
# Command failed: ('/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/makaldiap/Desktop/New Folder/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug')
```

My cyhton versiyon is 0.29.26.
I try clean and run, p4a.branch = develop, recheck instalations but i can't solve. How can i solve this. Or is another vay to convert apk?

Comment: Could you please be more precise and provide your github action script and a complete error log ?